# CSS styling for a specific table

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been asked to remove the grey areas from this page http://ccl.vincentandbell.com/partners/

I have tried giving the table an ID `<div id="customtable">`, and have added the following in my style.css file:

```
#customtable { 
    background-color: #fffff;
}
```

However, this didn't change the color of the gray areas.

---

Here's the HTML of one grey area:

```
<tr>
    <td width="105"></td>
    <td width="498"><strong>&nbsp;</strong><p></p>
        <h3>Cumbria Methodist District</h3>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.cumbriamethodistdistrict.org.uk/welcome.htm">http://www.cumbriamethodistdistrict.org.uk/welcome.htm</a>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the CSS applied to it:

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it more easily understandable by those who might be able to help you. Please think about including the name of the theme you're using, and a link to its webpage. I used Chrome's [devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) to find the HTML of the grey areas and the CSS applied to them (however there are similar tools in every web browser). Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a class here :

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(even)
```

you need to overwrite this class :

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
  table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
```

TO

```
 table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: transparent;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Note: you used `#fffff` as a color value, which is an invalid color value - use eiter `#fff` or `#ffffff` (6 times `f`)

2.) Theoretically, it should work with this CSS added, as @Daniel Fois wrote, since that corresponds to / overwrites an original CSS rule:

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

3.) If it should be restricted to that particular page (and not the whole website), you can use the page ID class `page-id-16` (which is in the body tag) in a combined CSS selector, plus add `!important`, if necessary:

```
.page-id-16 table tr {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```